# Ruby, cannot round a float

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to round a float...

I have this string

```
pry(main)> row[8]
=> "   8.021"

row[8].to_f
=> 8.021

pry(main)> row[8].to_f*1000
=> 8021.000000000001

pry(main)> row[8].to_f*1000.floor
=> 8021.000000000001
```

I need to remove the 0000

Comment: Floating point mathc has precision issues (you can looki t up just about anywhere including SO). So you can explicitly round `(row[8].to_f*1000).round(2)` or you can use the BigDecimal class which handles mathematical precision much better `require 'bigdecimal'; BigDecimal(row[8]).*(1000).to_f`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
("   8.021".to_f * 1000).floor
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with precision

Your code

```
pry(main)> row[8].to_f*1000.floor
=> 8021.000000000001
```

is actually doing floor on integer value:

```
pry(main)> row[8].to_f * (1000.floor)
=> 8021.000000000001
```

Doesn't have a sense if you want to use the floor correctly to round the float number
So you should go with

```
pry(main)> (row[8].to_f * 1000).floor
=> 8021.000000000001
```

Multiplication first, then `floor` method

Answer (score 0):

You just discovered the [accuracy problems in floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) that can be avoided by using [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead of floats.

But instead of that, it is useful to learn how Ruby understands your code.

When you write

```
row[8].to_f*1000.floor
```

then Ruby reads it as

```
row[8].to_f * ( 1000.floor )
```

Because the `floor` method call has higher precedence than the `*` operation.

Therefore you need to tell Ruby exactly in which order to interpret your code:

```
( row[8].to_f * 1000 ).floor
# => 8021
```